# getting error in hdfs.init() in rhdfs

Tags: r, hadoop

I want to run `hdfs.init()`, my code is:

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="C:\\hdp\\hadoop\\hadoop-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-0380\\bin\\hadoop")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR="C:\\hdp\\hadoop\\hadoop-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-0380\\conf")
library(rhdfs)
hdfs.init()
```

after executing `hdfs.init()` I get an error like below:

```
> hdfs.init()
Error in .jnew("org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration") : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
```

Answer (score 1):

Download this [jar](https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com/cloudera/hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/hadoop-core-0.20.2-737.jar)  and try :

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="C:\\hdp\\hadoop\\hadoop-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-0380\\bin\\hadoop")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR="C:\\hdp\\hadoop\\hadoop-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-0380\\conf")
.jinit()
.jaddClassPath("/path/to/jar/hadoop-core-0.20.2-737.jar")
library(rhdfs)
hdfs.init()
```

make sure java is loaded in R

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at `JAVA_HOME` and `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`. This conf (although might be redundant) worked for me on MacOS after a painful Sunday morning :-) - you will need to do the required changes depending on your machine, install and OS but at least you have a clue.

```
Sys.setenv ("JAVA_HOME"="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre")
Sys.setenv ("HADOOP_PREFIX"="/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1")
Sys.setenv ("HADOOP_CMD"="/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/bin/hadoop")
Sys.setenv ("HADOOP_STREAMING"="/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.8.1.jar")
Sys.setenv ("HADOOP_CLASSPATH"="/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/libexec/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/libexec/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/libexec/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/libexec/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/libexec/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/libexec/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/libexec/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar")
```